# Regex in rewrite.xml

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I'm writing new rule in rewrite.xml

i want an address (friendly url) like 
http://adam.com/search?q=123

will go to

http://adam.com/blablabla.aspx?q=123

i need to do it in this XML structure.

```
<ruleset r301="" rewrite="^/search(.*)">
    <rule type="rewrite" hndlr="search">
      <source>^/search(.*)</source>
      <target>/blablabla.aspx</target>
    </rule>
  </ruleset>
```

but it doesn't work well. can someone knows why ?

Comment: *it doesn't work well* - then, how does it work?

Comment: Try `^/search\b([^/.]*)/?$` (`/?` is for optional trailing slash - remove if not necessary) and rewrite with `/blablabla.aspx{R:1}`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/oJ7zT6/1

Comment: what sort of configuration language is that?  can you add proper tags, and specify exactly how is it not working "well"?

Comment: Thanks Every one @WiktorStribiżew and cnst .i solved the problem, this is something else, not common regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^/search\b([^/.]*)/?$
```

and rewrite with `/blablabla.aspx{R:1}`. The `/?` is for an optional trailing slash - remove if not necessary.

The `^/search\b([^/.]*)/?$` pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `/search\b` - a whole word `/search`
- `([^/.]*)` - Group 1 (later, references to as `{R:1}`) matching 0+ characters other than `/` and `.`
- `/?` - 1 or 0 `/` symbols
- `$` - end of string.